# Prevent child div from expanding outside of parent?

Tags: html, css

Jsfiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ibrewster/g6v2x7ku/12/

Note how the pink div expands beyond the boarders of the blue div.

I'm trying to make a simple layout where I have two nested divs that expand up to a certain height (100% of the window height is desired in this case), with the inner div scrolling as needed to show additional content. So if the content is short, the divs all collapse down to the size of the content, but if it is long they only expand to a point, at which time the inner div should scroll.

The HTML:

```
<div id="topDiv">
  <div id="insideDiv">
    Some inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Note that the effect is the same if the max-height of `topDiv` is set to a percentage, under which scenario I can't simply set the max-height value of `insideDiv` to an appropriately smaller value. Also, setting the `overflow` property on `topDiv` to hidden doesn't work - the extra content in `insideDiv` is simply completely hidden then, not accessible by scrolling.

How can I limit the height of `insideDiv` to not exceed the height of `topDiv`, with `insideDiv` scrolling any extra content as needed?

Comment: `max-height:inherit`, assuming you'll always set the max-height on your parent. Would also want to put `box-sizing: border-box;` on `#insideDiv` so you can freely set its padding/borders.

Comment: What about `overflow: scroll`

Comment: @Abhi will always show the scrollbar, but will not restrict the height. Seems like the issue is that `max-height` as a percentage looks for a `height` on its parent, and can't find one, so you run into the usual "nondeterministic relative height" problem.

Comment: Why not to set the overflow on the outer div? https://jsfiddle.net/g6v2x7ku/23/ nothing needs to be set on the inner one.

Comment: @panglos because I don't want the outer div to scroll, I want the inner div to scroll. In the actual code, there is some stuff in the outer div before the inner div that I want to keep visible. If the outer div scrolled, then the other stuff in the outer div would scroll off the screen, which I don't want. Thus the reason the inner div is what needs to scroll.

Comment: Does #topDiv have a fixed pixels height / max-height or it should be a percentage height? As your whole set up makes it to look like it will be a percentage height.

Comment: @pangloss I've found the same effect either way. I used fixed pixels in my example because it was easier to show the issue, but yes, my production code uses percent.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can change your `#insideDiv`'s `max-height` CSS property from `100%` to `inherit`. So this rule will be like this:

`max-height: inherit;`

You also might want to add `box-sizing:border-box;` if you go this route, as that will allow any borders or padding on `#insideDiv` to behave as (probably) desired.

---

The cause of this issue is that `max-height:100%;` looks for the parent's `height`, not its `max-height` for how tall it's allowed to be. Thus, you end up with the classic non-deterministic relative height problem. If you give the parent a deterministic `height` (rather than `max-height`), `100%` can resolve deterministically.

Comment: It looks like this should work, I'll have to make sure I didn't oversimplify the issue such that it breaks on my production code :)

Comment: Will probably also want `box-sizing:border-box` so any border/padding changes on `#insideDiv` still behave right. As to why I made a comment instead of an answer: I felt that using `inherit` here is a tad.... hacky? Technically you should put the height limit on `#insideDiv` with this setup, so I didn't wanna say it "solved" the problem- more just worked around it. Kudos for noting the comments had it, btw. Not enough people do that.

Comment: In fact it was the first thing I tried and worked. If the best practice is to implement it in another way, then the OP should go ahead and use that way (I confess that I am a bit lazy and unorthodox sometimes).

Just a moment after posting my answer, I saw your comment, so I'd thought it would be appropriate to mention your contribution, so I edited. Feel free to make any edits you think are necessary.

Comment: @abluejelly: Agreed re: box-sizing. I find I need that quite often. I'll have to look at setting the height limit on `#insideDiv` - I didn't do that at first because with the actual, non-simplified code it seemed more straight forward to set the height of the outer div. It might still work though.

Comment: @Arkoudinos Nah dude you're fine, and I do that too. Just thought I'd toss in my reasoning for not jumping to the answer post instead of the comments. I think I'll add an explanation as to why this was a problem, just gotta make sure I do it right

Comment: It's generally a good practice to do this:   * {  box-sizing: border-box; }

Answer (score 12):

Try this flexbox layout, it works fine with either fixed or percentage height / max-height.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7uq6z90/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#topDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#insideDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
  <div>
    No scroll content
  </div>
  <div id="insideDiv">
    Some inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>More inside content
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! The `overflow-y: auto;` was all I needed to add. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move `overflow-y:auto;` to `#topDiv`

You can then modify your max-height values to whatever you want for either and they will work as expected.

Comment: that makes `#topDiv` be the one scrolling, and doesn't actually limit the height of `#insideDiv`

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misread the issue. I agree with the other answers then.

Answer (score 2):

There is one line answer, if you apply `max-height` and `overflow` property don't forget to give `position:relative` to the same element!

That's what helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question.  This code should work very well!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#topDiv {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: calc (100% - 20px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

#insideDiv {
  width: calc (100% - 40px);
  background-color: pink;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
  <div id="insideDiv">
    Some inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6v2x7ku/22/) with the code as well.

Comment: No, I don't want the topDiv to scroll - I want the insideDiv to scroll, and never get large enough that the topDiv would even want to scroll.

Comment: Makes the parent div scroll, doesn't make the child div scroll. The issue is the child div has no height restriction.

Comment: @JeffArries Now you're setting the max height to 100% of the screen height, which means the page can always generate a vertical scroll bar of its own. You also removed the `50px` limit set previously, overrode the `overflow-y` to `scroll` so the scrollbars are always visible even when not needed (the difference between `scroll` and `auto`), and left the old `max-height:100%` letting the cascade hide the bloat. Can I downvote a second time?

Comment: Hmmmm....that could work. Different way of thinking about it, with the height restriction being on the inside div rather than the top.

Comment: So this doesn't really resolve the question as I posted it (it looks like max-height:inherit; is what I want) - the points made by ableujelly are spot-on. However, it actually did help a different issue I was dealing with, so thanks!

Comment: @ibrewster Please humor me and take a look at my JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/g6v2x7ku/22/, that should work perfectly!

Comment: Indeed it does - of course, that uses the max-height inherit trick that other users have already answered, and has overflow: scroll rather than overflow: auto. Still, thanks!

Comment: @ibrewster You are far more polite that I think I'll ever be. Don't ever change haha

Comment: @ibrewster All I used from other answers was `overflow: inherit;`.  I also give you a finished answer. But do whatever you want!  I'm just glad I was of (some) use!

Comment: Interesting point: if I change the max-height: calc() on the outer div from 100vh to 100%, it breaks. Could be part of the reason I was having so much trouble.

Comment: @ibrewster  Yes, `width: 100%;` equals 100% of the browser window width, if you use `width: 100vh;` (viewport height) that makes it 100% of the browser window height.  That one of the only ways to set an element to the height of the browser.  P.S. it works with `vh` and `vw`.

Comment: No, not width: max-height. You specified the `max-height` attribute in topDiv as `max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);`, if I change the 100vh to100%, we're back to the original problem. But 100vh does seem to work.

Comment: @ibrewster Sorry, I stated that badly.  `100%` gets its value from the browser width, whereas `100vh` gets its value from the browser height.  Understand better now?